# Running both aspx and .Net Core (.Net 5) webpages on same server and domain

Tags: redirect, .net-core, webforms

I am about to move a webshop from old webforms to new .Net Core (.Net 5) site.
The old urls have a lot of good rating on google and I would like to be able to make a permanent redirect from an aspx page to .net core page.
Etc.:

[www.mydomain.com/products/great-backpack-1234.aspx](http://www.mydomain.com/products/great-backpack-1234.aspx)

to

[www.mydomain.com/great-backpack](http://www.mydomain.com/great-backpack)

I  believe that requires that I have both .net core and aspx site running on the same domain.
Is this possible?
Or do any one have any other solution ideas?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably not needed to run both on the same domain or space. It seems everything will end in .aspx, and assuming you are using MVC, a controller function to catch-all requests that don't match other routes, then check to see if it ends in aspx, should do it for you. You can put it in an existing controller, but I personally would put it in a new one to separate concerns

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    [Route("{**url}", Order = 999)]
    public IActionResult RedirectPage(string url)
    {
       //Redirect logic based on the URL given, making sure it ends in aspx
    }
}
```

The url would come across in the url parameter as a string and you can check to see if it ends in aspx, and what the page name was to determine where to send them. So "www.mydomain.com/products/great-backpack-1234.aspx" would come across in the url parameter as "products/great-backpack-1234.aspx". Note that the order field in the route attribute assures that it will be the last match checked for patterns, so it shouldn't mess with anything else.